# Como puedo calcular el porcentaje de notas en C#

Tags: c#

```
class Alumnos{
    static void Main(string [] args){
        int CantRepro=0, CantApro=0, i=1;
        double promGrupo=0, PromAproba=0, PromDesapro=0, nota=0;
        string resp;

        Console.WriteLine("Desea introducir datos?   S/N");
        resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        while(resp == "s"){

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la nota obtenida");
            nota = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if(nota <=5){

                CantRepro++;
            }
            else if(nota >=6){

                CantApro++;
            }
            promGrupo =  nota /nota;

            if(promGrupo>=6){
                PromAproba++;
            }
            else if(promGrupo<=5){
                PromDesapro++;
            }
            i++;

            Console.Write("Desea Continuar  S/N ");
            resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();            

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de aprobados es:"+CantApro);
        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de reprobados es:"+CantRepro);
        Console.WriteLine("El promedio grupal es de:"+promGrupo);   
        Console.WriteLine("El promedio aprobado es de:"+PromAproba);
        Console.WriteLine("El promedio desaprobado es de:"+PromDesapro);
    }
}
```

Este es el enunciado:
Calcular lo siguiente:
a) Cuantos reprobados.
b) Cuantos aprobados.
c) El promedio general del grupo.
d) El promedio de notas aprobadas y reprobadas

Hasta ahorita solo he podido hacer los literales A y B pero no sé como sacar el promedio general del grupo y el promedio de notas aprobadas y reprobadas
lo demas no sé si esta bien.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. ¿qué errores tienes con este código?

Answer (score 1):

Es que no estas haciendo bien la lógica de los promedios, debes tener un acumulador global de todas las notas y dividirlas por el número de iteraciones, y en lo otro debes tomar el total de aprobados y reprobados y dividirlos por el número de iteraciones también:

Aqui puedes realizar una [prueba](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IZhbrL).

```
class Alumnos
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int CantRepro=0, CantApro=0, i=0;
        double promGrupo=0, PromAproba=0, PromDesapro=0, nota=0;
        string resp;
        Console.WriteLine("Desea introducir datos?   S/N");
        resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        while(resp == "s"){
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la nota obtenida");
            nota = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if(nota <=5)
                CantRepro++;
            if(nota >=6)
                CantApro++;
            promGrupo += nota;
            Console.Write("Desea Continuar  S/N ");
            resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        }
        promGrupo = promGrupo/i;
        PromAproba = ((double)CantApro/i)*100;
        PromDesapro = ((double)CantRepro/i)*100;
        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de aprobados es:"+CantApro);
        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de reprobados es:"+CantRepro);
        Console.WriteLine("El promedio grupal es de:"+promGrupo);   
        Console.WriteLine("El promedio aprobado es de:"+PromAproba+"%");
        Console.WriteLine("El promedio desaprobado es de:"+PromDesapro+"%");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es una evaluación al parecer, hay varias opciones, lo más simple con lo que tienes:
Declara un entero:

```
int cantidadNotas = 0; // cada vez que ingreses una nota suma 1
```

Cambia esta variable para llevar la sumatoria

```
promGrupo =  promGrupo  + nota;
```

Realiza la división en el retorno:

```
Console.WriteLine("El promedio grupal es de:"+ (promGrupo / cantidadNotas));
```

Comment: Ahora, como son 3 promedios tienes dos opciones, llevas un sumarizado y un contador para aprobados y reprobados o almacenas las notas en un array y utilizas un ciclo para obtener los promedios.

Answer (score 0):

Estas calculando mal los promedios. Primero debes sumar la cantidad de reprobados, cantidad de aprobados, sumar las notas de los reprobados y sumar las notas de los aprobados para poder realizar los calculos, aquí te dejo el código corregido y la imagen de consola ejecutando el código.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJjcq.png

```
class Alumnos
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         int CantRepro = 0, CantApro = 0, i = 1;
            double promGrupo = 0, PromAproba = 0, PromDesapro = 0, nota = 0;
            string resp;
            Console.WriteLine("Desea introducir datos?   S/N");
            resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            while (resp == "s")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la nota obtenida");
                nota = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (nota <= 5)
                {
                    CantRepro++;
                    PromDesapro += nota;
                }
                else
                {
                    CantApro++;
                    PromAproba += nota;
                }   
                i++;
                Console.Write("Desea Continuar  S/N ");
                resp = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            }
            promGrupo = (PromDesapro + PromAproba) / (i-1);
            PromAproba = (CantApro * 100) / (i - 1);
            PromDesapro = (CantRepro * 100) / (i - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de aprobados es:" + CantApro);
            Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de reprobados es:" + CantRepro);
            Console.WriteLine("El promedio grupal es de:" + promGrupo + "%");
            Console.WriteLine("El promedio aprobado es de:" + PromAproba + "%");
            Console.WriteLine("El promedio desaprobado es de:" + PromDesapro + "%");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```